# IMCE stops uploading image in the middle of uploading

Tags: 6, media, files

I have a very strange case. I am using IMCE 6.x-2.2. and when my editors try to upload a new image, it stops uploading in the middle of the process and gives message: "A file with the specified name already exists.".
now when i check on the server, i found that it has uploaded part of the image only (image cropped).
this happens always on google chrome and sometimes on Firefox!!
any idea is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find the string "A file with the specified name already exists" anywhere in the source of [IMCE 6.x-2.2](http://drupal.org/node/1180416).

Looks like the same issue was noted [here on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1187924) and was not part of IMCE

I would recommend updating to the newest version of IMCE in the 6 series to see if this fixes the issue. (Currently 6.x-2.3)